# Bijection between set of real numbers R and the cantor set in R.

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to find a bijection mapping from **R to the cantor set**?

(We know that the set of all real numbers and the cantor sets are uncountable sets). Give some ideas to construct a bijection mapping between these two sets.!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure we can!

**First strategy: Cantor-Bernstein.** Find a pair of injective functions, one going from the Cantor set $C$ to the reals $\mathbb{R}$, the other going from $\mathbb{R}$ to $C$. The first is easy - just take the inclusion map! For the second, let me sketch instead how to give an injection from $(0, 1)$ to $C$. Given $x\in (0, 1)$, take its binary expansion (the one **without** an infinite trail of $1$s, if it has two binary expansions) and change all the $1$s to $2$s. Viewing this as a ternary expansion, this yields a real in $C$! (To replace $(0, 1)$ with $\mathbb{R}$ is easy; e.g. precompose with $\arctan$.)

The Cantor-Bernstein theorem then tells us (explicitly!) how to combine these two injections to get a bijection. It's messy, though.

**Second strategy: binary expansions.** We can also come up with a bijection explicitly, using binary expansions - basically, modifying the construction of the injection $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow C$ given above, appropriately. This is a bit tricky, but not really hard; I'll leave the details as an exercise.

**Is there a nice bijection?** Unfortunately, not really - there is no *continuous* bijection between $C$ and $\mathbb{R}$. This follows e.g. from the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact, but $C$ is (or many other differences between them).

Comment: Both bijections have nice property of being Borel isomorphisms  (i.e. Borel measurable with their inverses).